# Difference between dictionary unpacking operator vs copy.deepcopy?

Tags: python, copy, deep-copy

Time to time I need to deepcopy an object and sometimes it's a dictionary object so I use `**` operator to copy it easily but I always wondered if deepcopy is any different or efficient in some sense.
Which one is more efficient in terms of memory footprint, cpu time and does deepcopy iterate over like `**` operator does?

```py
import copy
myObj = {"some": "data", "to": "copy"}

# With using unpacking operator.
newObj1 = {**myObj}

# With using `copy.deepcopy` function.
newObj2 = copy.deepcopy(myObj)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful; there's a big difference when those dictionary values are mutable, and `**` does not behave equivalently to `copy.deepcopy()`:

```
>>> import copy
>>> myObj = {"some": "data", "to": ["copy", "this"]}
>>> newObj1 = {**myObj}
>>> newObj2 = copy.deepcopy(myObj)
>>> myObj["to"][1] = "that"
>>> newObj1
{'some': 'data', 'to': ['copy', 'that']}
>>> newObj2
{'some': 'data', 'to': ['copy', 'this']}
```

As shown in [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/#rationale), using `**` iterable unpacking is more akin to `dict.copy()` than `copy.deepcopy()`.

Comment: So the real object does not get mutated when you change `newObj1` but if you change the main object it mutates the inherited objects in `newObj1` too, did I get it right?

Comment: @GuvenDegirmenci in this case, changing elements of `newObj1['to']` will mutate `myObj`. They both contain references to the same mutable list.

Comment: Looks like there is some odd problem: https://repl.it/talk/share/Odd-Behaviour/80345

Comment: I guess this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/184745/7493063) explains the problem.